Why does Flixbus let me book Norrköping-Joensuu but not Norrköping-Helsinki when Helsinki is an earlier stop on the Hamburg-Joensuu line?
Now, before anyone tells me that I just should fly — I know that it would be both more practical and likely cheaper to fly on such a route. But I still felt interested in making this journey for other reasons. Anyway …

I'm looking into travelling to Helsinki while leaving from Norrköping. Previously a friend told me that he read in a local newspaper that Flixbus had applied for starting a Hamburg-Joensuu line in Autumn of this year, and so they did. This lead me to be curious if I could go all the way from Norrköping to Joensuu, and the Flixbus booking interface did indeed let me book such a journey with a single transfer in Berlin:

Fast forward a few months and I now have an actual reason to visit Helsinki, which is an earlier stop on the Hamburg-Joensuu line, and naturally I felt curious if I could then go Norrköping-Helsinki too. But the Flixbus booking interface doesn't let me do this:

This doesn't make any sense to me given that Helsinki is a stop on the Hamburg-Joensuu line — one of three stops, no less if you include Helsinki-Vantaa airport — and conceivably I could probably buy a Norrköping-Joensuu ticket and then just sneak off at one of the Helsinki stops. As I understand that is against Flixbus' rules however, and it surely wouldn't work for the return trip.
Either way, is there any explanation to why Flixbus won't sell my preferred connection in this situation?

Licenses? I have regional and local buses at my city. They share some stops. But I cannot use a regional bus to move between stops inside the city, because routes inside the city are serviced by local buses.

The Hamburg-Helsinki leg seems available when searching for it separately, it's the connection in Berlin that seems to cause problems.

Berlin-Helsinki is available too, though.

There are some other stops which work, and some other stops which don't. It's pretty weird, I wonder if they didn't just forget to load prices for some combinations or something like that.

I second jcaron here, that it is probably just a missing price or enablement in Flixbus' booking system. From experience working as a software developer with other travel booking systems, it might very well be that all bookable combinations of single legs must be explicitely enabled (as opposed to prohibiting invalid combinations).

Does flixbus have a phone booking option? It could be that even if you can't book it on a website, that a phone agent could do it.

53½ hours?  What route does it take?  Google Transit finds routes combining trains, buses, and ferries in under 24 hours.  Even going the long way around via Haparanda is substantially faster.  I will never tell anyone to fly, but there should be faster ways for overland travel.

@NateEldredge I can't find anything like that, but I'd guess it's a no given their low-cost business model.

@gerrit As mentioned in the post, it includes a single transfer in Berlin.
